# Should Stack Exchange sites use time-sensitive themed icons or images?

Tags: feature-request, design, logo

Should Stack Exchange sites use time-sensitive themed icons or images, like Google does with its Google Doodles?

[image: sample Google Doodle]

Comment: I don't understand your question?

Comment: like what @Gamecat said, the special logo design or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean to suggest special designs for the site to memorate certain special days like google does.

SO has done some kind of this, with the cornify period. So it can be done, The question is if we want it and for which days.

Comment: today is x'mas (tot is 26th for asia)